Mixed Integer Quadratic Program (MIQP): Kernel crashes during computation
I am solving an optimal placement problem using MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Program, using the QuadraticOptimization function WM version 14). The objective function is quadratic and decision variables are either 0 or 1. The total number of continuous variables is 96360 with 96360 times 2 constraints (lower bound and upper bound). The number of decision variables is 11.
I am optimizing throughout the year, hence the number of variables is quite large.
During computation the kernel crashes, without any error messages. It seems to me that there is a problem with memory allocation.
When I do the computation for, say, 50 days, the script works fine.
So the problem is essentially in handling a larger number of variables.
Also, I specifically define that continuous variables are vectors of the given size and type Reals using (Element[x, Vectors[nDays*24, Reals]]).
I would appreciate suggestions how to deal with the issue.
Here is a simplified example:
ClearAll["Global`*"]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
$HistoryLength = 2;
nNodes = 5;
(*random data*)
dataRN = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {365*24, nNodes}];

nDays = 5;

(* decision variables that are treated as vectors of length nDays times 24 *)
vars = ToExpression["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[nNodes];
(* decision variables that set which nodes are equipped with load*)
varsConst = ToExpression["a" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[nNodes];
(* auxilary variables that help to pass data to the objective function*)
auxvars = ToExpression["q" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[nNodes];
lessthanconst = 
  VectorLessEqual[{#1, #2*120}] & @@@ Transpose[{vars, varsConst}];
greaterthanconst = VectorGreaterEqual[{#, 0}] & /@ vars;
auxconstIntegers = Thread[1 >= varsConst >= 0];

objectiveF = (#1 - #2) . (#1 - #2) & @@@ Transpose[{auxvars, vars}];

auxconst = Thread[auxvars ==  Transpose@dataRN[[;; nDays*24]]];
solopt = QuadraticOptimization[Total[objectiveF],
   {auxconst, lessthanconst, greaterthanconst, Total[varsConst] == 2, 
    auxconstIntegers},
   {Alternatives @@ vars \[Element] Vectors[nDays*24, Reals], 
    Element[varsConst, Integers]}];


Since your scaled down example works, you may be right about memory. Can you monitor memory usage from the OS to see if you run out? It's hard to be more specific without actual code to run.

Thank you for the comment. I provided a simplified example of the problem.

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I can run your code on "14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" without a problem. With nDays = 50, I get a result in around 100 seconds. Can you please try increasing your nDays to see when it breaks down or whether it is only 50 that is problematic?

Thank you for the comment.
Well, the case, that I am currently working on has 11 nodes (nNodes = 11) and optimization is done throughout the year. The solver was able to compute for 180 days. However, I want to be able to increase number of nodes and optimize for the whole year.
My workstation is quite new and has 64 Gb RAM. I am not sure how the solver works with that memory, does it use hard disk to store something or not?
Regarding previous comment, I looked the RAM usage is through the roof during computation.
So, It seems that there is problem in the subroutine.
